# CentOS 6.5 password-less scp fails only when ssh server not running debug

Tags: centos6

I've got a very weird situation going on. I've got 3 database servers, 1 primary with 2 hot standby. These are running CentOS 6.5 and postgres 9.3.3 with WAL segment archiving so the primary needs to copy WAL files by itself, and it cannot tolerate a standby demanding a password for the copy operation.

I have generated the ssh key using ssh-keygen both specifying "-t rsa" and not, and I've both manually copied the id_rsa.pub file into the standby's authorized_keys file and I've tried ssh-copy-id as well. The standby does appear to have the right contents for proper operation.

The weird part is, if I turn on debugging on the standby servers sshd daemon, a can ssh into the standby without it prompting for a password, but if I do not have debugging active on the standby, it DOES demand a password.

Comment: that's a strange situation.  I'd check the ownership and permissions of your "authorized_keys" files and ".ssh" folders - most likely culprit imo.

Comment: which commands exactly do you use to connect, and how do you call them,interactively or from cron?

Comment: The commands are called internally by postgresql about every 10 minutes. I believe it spawns a shell then waits for it to exit.

Comment: More weirdness, my second machine can ssh to the first machine without a password. I tried de-installing openssh-clients and openssh-server on both and reinstalling, but the situation didn't change. I've run ssh -v on both system, one working, one not, and they are different. The working one isn't looking for a the local user's ssh_config file, the broken one is, and the files are then identical until a line reading "debug 1: Next authentication method" Here, the working one says gssapi-keyex and the broken one says publickey. Where is this controlled in the configuration?